# Python Dask AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'broadcast_to'

Tags: python, dask, attributeerror

I have written a code to try out Dask for utilizing multiple processors on my Unix server, as shown below:

```
import pandas as pd
import sys
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask.multiprocessing import get


numbers = pd.read_csv("head_5_22SNPs_CMI.txt", sep="\t", header=None)

combinations = pd.read_csv("all_combinations_5snps.txt", sep=" ", header=None)

data_dask = dd.from_pandas(combinations, npartitions=5)

pop = int(1 + 5)

score_col, freq_col = [], []

def score_freq(line):
    score=0
    freq=1
    for j in range(len(line)):
        if line[j][1] != numbers.values[j][1]:   # homozygous for ref
            score+=0
            freq*=(float(1-float(numbers.values[j][pop]))*float(1-float(numbers.values[j][pop])))
        elif line[j][0] != numbers.values[j][1] and line[j][1] == numbers.values[j][1]: # heterozygous
            score+=(float(numbers.values[j][5]))
            freq*=(2*(float(1-float(numbers.values[j][pop]))*float(numbers.values[j][pop])))
        elif line[j][0] == numbers.values[j][1]:
            score+=2*(float(numbers.values[j][5]))
            freq*=(float(numbers.values[j][pop])*float(numbers.values[j][pop]))

        if freq < 1e-5:   # threshold to stop loop in interest of efficiency 
            break


    return pd.Series([score, freq])

res = data_dask.map_partitions(lambda df: df.apply((lambda row: score_freq(row)), axis=1)).compute(scheduler=get)

res.to_csv('dask_test.txt', index=False)
```

I am getting an error when running this code on my Unix server:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "compute_scores_pandas+dask_testing.py", line 3, in <module>
    import dask.dataframe as dd
  File "/hpc/home/lsiwzyj/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .core import (DataFrame, Series, Index, _Frame, map_partitions,
  File "/hpc/home/lsiwzyj/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py", line 19, in <module>
    from .. import array as da
  File "/hpc/home/lsiwzyj/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dask/array/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .core import (Array, block, concatenate, stack, from_array, store,
  File "/hpc/home/lsiwzyj/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dask/array/core.py", line 31, in <module>
    from . import chunk
  File "/hpc/home/lsiwzyj/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dask/array/chunk.py", line 19, in <module>
    broadcast_to = npcompat.broadcast_to
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'broadcast_to'
```

After some Googling, it seems that this problem could be a clash between class names, but I can't seem to figure out any in my script. I have also tried upgrading the Dask package, I did get a warning as such:

```
Cannot uninstall 'python-dateutil'. It is a distutils installed project anthus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would ld to only a partial uninstall.
```

Does anyone know what the problem is? The script is working on Windows in my IDE.

Comment: Please include details of how you installed dask, and the current versions; also, when using multiprocessing, it is best to use `if __name__ == __main__` guards.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I used `pip install dask` on my Unix server to install dask, and the current version is 0.20.0. I get this message when trying to install again `Requirement already satisfied: dask in /hpc/home/lsiwzyj/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages (0.20.0)`.

Comment: You may want to try `pip install "dask[complete]"`, but this is being discussed here: https://github.com/dask/dask/pull/4168

Answer (score 1):

<strike>The problem is name collision in two libraries:
[This](http://%20https://github.com/dask/dask/blob/master/dask/array/numpy_compat.py#L19) tries to import `broadcast_to` from name `npcompat` which is confused by two different definitions [here](https://github.com/dask/dask/blob/master/dask/array/numpy_compat.py) and [possibly here](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/blob/master/xarray/core/npcompat.py), the latter is a guess though.</strike>

There was a bug in dask which is discussed [here](https://github.com/dask/dask/pull/4168), as referenced by @mdurant in comments above.

<strike>It looks like you don't have `numpy` installed, and installing that would be my solution unless there is a strong reason not to do so.</strike>

On reading your comment, I'm not very sure about the cause (so not being so useful here) and have to dig in further, but I'd start with getting rid of that warning. You can do so by removing python-dateutil using `conda remove` command. Upgrading dask again, then, will install it again (with latest version) and should not show that warning.

Comment: Hi, thanks and sorry for the late reply. I have tried to install numpy using pip, but it seems that I already have version 1.7.1 installed. I can see how the problem may be a name collision issue, how should I direct the script into importing from the right directory?

Answer (score 0):

So I found this issue too when creating a requirements.txt file for a module filled with functions decorated with dask delayed. Since the dask back-end code appears to be buggy, I found a workaround by using:

```
import dask.delayed as delayed

@delayed
def some_fun(x):
     return x
```

instead of

```
import dask
@dask.delayed
def some_fun(x):
     return x
```

Quirky, but it works and is much more robust to various environments I place it in.